# Invalidate all sessions at application reload

Tags: tomcat, session

is there a way that tomcat 7 invalidates all sessions of an application when it is reloaded manually via the management interface?

All the best,
Thomas

Comment: Was my answer helpful, Thomas?

Answer (score 3):

From the Tomcat doc:

> **Persistence Across Restarts**
>
> Whenever Apache Tomcat is shut down
>   normally and restarted, or when an application reload is triggered,
>   the standard Manager implementation will attempt to serialize all
>   currently active sessions to a disk file located via the pathname
>   attribute. All such saved sessions will then be deserialized and
>   activated (assuming they have not expired in the mean time) when the
>   application reload is completed.
>
> In order to successfully restore the state of session attributes, all
>   such attributes MUST implement the java.io.Serializable interface. You
>   MAY cause the Manager to enforce this restriction by including the
>    element in your web application deployment descriptor
>   (/WEB-INF/web.xml).
>
> **Disable Session Persistence**
>
> As documented above, every web application by default has standard
>   manager implementation configured, and it performs session persistence
>   across restarts. To disable this persistence feature, create a Context
>   configuration file for your web application and add the following
>   element there:

```
<Manager pathname="" />
```

> http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html#Persistence_Across_Restarts
>
> If you don't already have a META-INF/context.xml file,  you could use
>   this one:

```
<Context>
  <Manager pathname="" />
</Context>
```

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. In the future, please provide more context to your answers, as well as all relevant information from any links provided. If they go dead, your answer loses all its value.

Comment: What exactly would an example of "more context" be in this example downvoter GregL? The context is provided by reading the question before reading the answer. What additional context do you need in order to understand the answer?

Comment: The text from the section of the link you posted would probably suffice.

Answer (score 2):

See [Standard Manager Implementation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html) , you should set pathName to an empty string or  delete SESSIONS.ser before booting.